# Unable to get all comments of conversation thread of planner task

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

i am currently working on small project where i have to retrieve all comments of particular task in planner api (microsoft planner).

using microsoft graph api documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-thread?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

i tried to call below end points
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[GroupID]/threads/[ConversationID]

i replaced groupid and conversationId in above url and it works.

but it has two problem

1.) it return only one comment (recent comment), but i want to retrieve all comments.

2.) it shows only 250 character of comment (preview text), but i need to retrieve full comment.

can anyone help why api link give above two problem.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/posts will give you access to all the comments in a JSON array, and will have the full comment.  However the comment will have HTML embedded in the data.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[GroupID]/threads/[ConversationID]/posts
```

HTH